# Find Specific objects on Google street view with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-earth

please be patient with me, this is my first time using this site. I am currently working on my Eagle Project. My project is to locate all the existing Crime Stoppers street signs in my town. My problem right now is that I don't have an efficient way to search for 300 signs in a town of population 70,000 so I was wondering if I could make a program to do it for me. Is it at all possible to make a program using python to search google street view of my entire town and recognize a sign almost like facial recognition but for signs? I'm not sure whether or not this is a phesable task but just wanted to give it a shot :) thank you for your time, any and all responses or help are welcome and appreciated!

Comment: Yes. Lookup geopy and scikit-image.

Comment: This is not possible without some amazingly clever machine learning technology. In the meantime, please [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.